# How to get MySQLdb running on Mountain Lion with Python 2.7 and MySQL 5.6.11 x86_64

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have gone through various possibities of installing MySQL following hundreds of advice (e.g. here on stackoverflow) in order to get MySQLdb running. After having installed Xcode and Command Line Codes I solved the initial `command 'clang' failed with exit status 1` error sitting now with the following error message: `mach-o, but wrong architecture`.
I have Python 64 bit, MySQL 64 bit installed (please see below). 
I have also installed mysql-connector-python-1.0.10.
What is the problem here?

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Python version:

```
>>>print (sys.version)
2.7.2 (default, Jun 16 2012, 12:38:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]

>>> print platform.architecture()
('64bit', '')
```

MySQL version:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 5.6.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show global variables like 'version_compile_machine';
+-------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name           | Value  |
+-------------------------+--------+
| version_compile_machine | x86_64 |
+-------------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK: MySQLdb requires MySQL not higher than Version 5.5. I had Version 5.6. 
So fixed it.